# Spring-ws multiple request in one request

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

I have a problem.
I want to create multiple request in one request.

```
<xsd:element name="SendMemberStatusRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="MemberStatusRequest" type="member:MemberStatusRequest"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:element name="SendMemberStatusResponse">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="MemberStatusResponse" type="member:MemberStatusResponse"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

This is my xsd code. For one "MemberStatusRequest" but i want to use, who want to send request may be send 1 request may be send 10 request. Anybody can help me ?

```
<xsd:element name="SendMemberStatusRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element  name="MemberStatusRequest" type="member:MemberStatusRequest"/>
        <xsd:element  name="MemberStatusRequest" type="member:MemberStatusRequest"/>
        .........
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Collections in XML SChema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5253400/collections-in-xml-schema)

Comment: Add a single `<xsd:element  name="MemberStatusRequest" type="member:MemberStatusRequest"/>` and specify the `maxOccurs` attribute.

Comment: Yes i add maxOccurs attribute and solved my problem. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you:

```
<xsd:element name="SendMemberStatusRequest">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:element name="MemberStatusRequest" type="member:MemberStatusRequest" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

By default `minOccurs/maxOccurs` is "1".

Your Request Class on the matter should have `List<MemberStatusRequest> requests` property.